# unable to acess another sheet in vba

Tags: vba, excel

i was trying to access the charts and pictures and the charts that are present in another workbook that lie in the same folder.  here is my code.

```
wbname = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1").Value
wsname = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A2").Value
MsgBox wbname
wbname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wbname    
MsgBox "reached here"
MsgBox "HI"
MsgBox Workbooks("C:\charts\1.xls").Sheet("L1-XO PGT ScoreCard").Range("A1:A1").Value
Set aWorkSheet = Workbooks("C:\charts\1.xls").Sheet("L1-XO PGT ScoreCard")
sCurrentSheet = aWorkSheet.Name
MsgBox "Shapes count " + CStr(aWorkSheet.Shapes.Count)
For iIndex = 1 To aWorkSheet.Shapes.Count
Set aShape = aWorkSheet.Shapes(iIndex)
MyPicture = aShape.Name
MsgBox aShape.Name + " Name, " + Str(aShape.Type)
If Left(aShape.Name, 7) = "Picture" Then
With aShape
PicHeight = .Height
PicWidth = .Width
End With
Set aChart = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=sCurrentSheet
iShapeCount = aWorkSheet.Shapes.Count
Set aShapeChart = aWorkSheet.Shapes(iShapeCount)
MyChart = aShapeChart.Name      '"Chart " & Str(aWorkSheet.Shapes.Count)
aShapeChart.Width = PicWidth
aShapeChart.Height = PicHeight
sChartJpg = sChartJpg & aShapeChart.Name & ".jpg"
With aWorkSheet
aShape.Copy
With ActiveChart 'aChart
.ChartArea.Select
.Paste
End With
.ChartObjects(iIndex).Chart.Export Filename:=sChartJpg, FilterName:="jpg",                    Interactive:=True
aShapeChart.Cut
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Completed."
Exit Sub
End If
Next
MsgBox "Completed."Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox "Error # " & CStr(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Source
Err.Clear   ' Clear the error.
 End Sub
```

After it displays "HI" alert box, it is Directly displaying the Completed testbox its not displaying the TestBOX alert 
"MsgBox Workbooks("C:\charts\1.xls").Sheet("L1-XO PGT ScoreCard").Range("A1:A1").Value" ... nor it is extracting the images from the workbook. can some one pls help

Comment: If you have something like `On Error Resume Next` somewhere, it would be a good time to remove it to better understand what is going on.

Comment: thanks for that .. i will remove it and see what error it does throw ..

Comment: it throws  subscript out of range on the line "MsgBox Workbooks("C:\charts\1.xls").Sheet("L1-XO PGT ScoreCard")"

Comment: Subscript out of range on a line like that means that either the workbook specified doesn't exist in the Workbooks collection or the sheet doesn't exist in the sheets one. Get rid of the path component of the workbook name; you should only be using the book name to access the workbook in that collection, not the full path. I just tested in xl2010 and found that if you use the path a subscript out of range error will be thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open the workbook - most of your code won't work on a closed workbook.